# How do you let users share one database file in android development?

Tags: android, sql, database

I am developing an Android application where users can upload their own recipes. So, I need to create only one database file and let the users share only this file. Is this even possible? I googled about uploading a database file on server and letting my application to manipulate the file but I did not find any good answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What programming language and framework are you using for your application?

Comment: It is android development.

Comment: Aren't you using any database in server side like MySQL? What do you mean by database file? Is it plain text or Android SQLLite database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to setup a SQL Database on your web server and from your apps make a http request to query the database, better yet, make a php script that accesses the db (much easier) and displays the relevant results, then use jsoup in Android and parse that php script for the information you need.

Comment: php is not the only server side language available.  If the OP is already conversent with java, coldfusion, .net, etc, he should use it.